# Creating a database from .mdf file in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, database, ms-access

I have a .mdf which I need to import into MS Access. I have read that .mdf is a Sql Server format so Access wont recognize it. But is there some way I can get the database created in MS Access. I am using Access 2003 and Sql Server 2005

Comment: open up SSMS and right-click ATTACH the database.  I do this a dozen times a day, it's quite simple.

Comment: That's an answer, Aaron, not a comment. You should post it separately, but you should add to it the fact that you have to have SQL Server installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not right click the database in SQL Management Studio, click export and then specify the required parameter?

I just checked. Works in my installation of SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new Access database and import the tables from the mdf file into it. You have not mentioned the version of Access or SQL server so it's difficult to be more specific.

Alternatively, if you have access to an SQL Server, you can export the database as an Access .mdb.